# Flutter, sign with both debug keys and release keys on Android

Tags: android, flutter

I followed the instructions to build release for Android and it was successful. https://flutter.io/docs/deployment/android#configure-signing-in-gradle

However, this project is open source and without the `keys.properties` file it will fail to build. This means that contributors are unable to run the project.

How do I setup `build.gradle` to sign debug with debug keys when doing a `--debug` or `--profile` build and with release keys from `keys.properties` with a `--release` build?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

this will use release keys only if the `key.properties` file exists

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            println "Signing with key.properties"
        } else {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            println "Signing with debug keys"
        }
    }
}
```